# Is it possible to generate custom bracket on the fly?

Tags: angular, software-design

I'm searching a way to generate component dynamically.
I know the ComponentFactoryResolver but it's not exactly what I want to do.
I would like to do something like that :

`<app-icon-x></app-icon-x>`

where 'x' is the name of an icon stored in a array.
I'm searching how I can iterate on that array and generate custom component usable directly in my html page.

Anyone have already do that? (not in angularjs because I know it's possible)

Thank you.

Comment: Currently we have a solution to generate component via a script but this one must be runed before deployement. (not dynamically).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating components on the fly, why don't you use the `@Input` decorator ? It would give you

```
<app-icon [iconName]="yourIconName"></app-icon>
```

Comment: Because I'm migrating our internal framework do with angular 1.x to 4 and I must have a retrocompatibility. Without this constraint, I will have used what you propose. :-(